# Geodjango: transform() swaps lat/long incorrectly

Tags: django, gdal, geodjango, coordinate-transformation

I'm using geodjango and load a shapefile as follows:

```
datasource = DataSource("/path/to/shape.shp")
for each in datasource[0]:
    geo = each.geom    
    geo.transform(4326)
```

What I'm trying to do here is to transform a geometry to 4326 so I can record it in my database, which uses this SRID. However, a rather odd thing happens. When I run this locally (using GDAL 2.4.0, Django 3.0.6) this works perfectly fine. Here is an example of a polygon that is transformed.

Input:

> POLYGON ((141192.63413501 167690.231242441,141198.39365501
> 167695.515882441...

Which is then transformed into:

> POLYGON ((4.24376514198078 50.8195815928706,4.24384675060931
> 50.819629186136...

This works well. However, when this runs in production (GDAL 3.0.4, Django 3.0.3), then this fails in a very weird way. There is no error message, and the transform() function does its thing... but it reverses latitude and longitude! So my output becomes:

> POLYGON ((50.8195818670687 4.24376485512428,50.8196294603646
> 4.24384646375124...

I can not fathom why this happens...?! It all seems to be fine, expect for this very odd swapping of lat/long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using different environments for development and production.

Django 3.0.3/3.0.6 does not create a problem (but it's better to upgrade to the latest patch release with `pip install django==3.0.* -U`).

But GDAL creates. You need at least read [GDAL migration guide](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/gdal/MIGRATION_GUIDE.TXT) before moving on to a new release.

3.0 have incompatible changes with axis which you seem to have encountered.

You can try method, that suggested [here](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1546#issuecomment-616344351):

```py
import osgeo

# ... so something to create and SRS:
srs = SpatialReference()

if int(osgeo.__version__[0]) >= 3:
    # GDAL 3 changes axis order: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/1546
    srs.SetAxisMappingStrategy(osgeo.osr.OAMS_TRADITIONAL_GIS_ORDER)
```

But your development and production environments must always match.

Comment: Great, thanks for this! It allowed me to better understand what was happening and to find a solution. Turns out that this particular problem was addressed in Django 3.1 so after upgrading to this version it is now compatible with GDAL 3. See this commit: https://github.com/django/django/commit/58f1b07e49a98bb391c9e38b91f078ab2c302703

Comment: @User402841 , I'm glad it helped you find a solution.